# DELETE query onclick automized

Tags: javascript, php, html

Having a slight problem here. I'm trying to create an admin side function to delete FAQ's, and despite the fact that I got a script working, I need to figure out how to automate a [WHERE clause] per added question.

To describe it, every question gets posted and has an ID in the database. I want to delete on that ID, but per question I add the

```
DELETE FROM faq [WHERE faq_id=#]
```

My current code:

```
$sql = "SELECT question, answer FROM faq";
          $queryresult = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

          while ($faqResult = mysql_fetch_array($queryresult)){
            $faqQuestion = $faqResult['question'];
            $faqAnswer = $faqResult['answer'];

            echo "<p class='faqQuestionAdmin'>$faqQuestion</p>" . 
            "<p class='faqAnswerAdmin'>$faqAnswer</p>" . 
            "<a class=faqDelete>X</a>";
          }
          if(mysql_num_rows($queryresult) <= 0) {
            echo("<div><p>No Questions available</p></div>");
          }

        mysql_free_result($queryresult);
        mysql_close($conn);
```

that serves as the deleting button. I was thinking a get function, but does anyone know how can I do this? Currently the only columns in the database for each question is the ID, question, and answer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean you want to have the X (delete button) for each question by his id?

Comment: yeah, if it's possible, otherwise if there is another method then I'd love to hear it too.

Comment: this seems very simple, when creating delete buttons give them same name as question id from database. then depend on what button you click on use DELETE from faq where faq_id = 'button_id'.

Comment: Check my answer with example :) I hope this is what you needed :-)

Comment: @BojanKovacevic that isn't possible. to do that I need to auto increment it, which in turn disables the question & answer's ID's auto increment function.

Comment: @eL-Prova I forgot to add my current code to call the question up. let me edit my question and post it.

Comment: did not get what you mean by that need to autoincrement it? At the time you print current faqs you have id. just select also id beside question and answer and use it for button name or even better as el prova said use it in link that process deleting that particular question.

Comment: @user3700201 where is the id? How you want to identify your question? You need an identifier. In most cases the Id...

Also faqDelete needs quotes. And how you want to post your button click?
My example shows to use a single file "delete.php" or use jQuery/AJAX to post the id. By adding to the a href: id='" . $result["YourId"] . "'. In the javascript click event you can get the id and make a post request

Comment: yeah yeah i have an ID for every question and answer. so i need a javascript function calling the php file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid AJAX, you could simply put a link in your anchor tag to php file with GET variable in it:

```
<a href="http://mysiteurl/php/deleteFAQ.php?id={faqid}">X</a>
```

Than in deleteFAQ.php you use

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = "DELETE FROM faq WHERE faq_id=$id";
```

Comment: it doesn't delete. It goes to the calling page with the ID in the url, but doesn't actually delete the question. plus I'd like it to auto refresh the page upon delete.

Comment: Do you get any mysql errors when you call it? I just tried on simple base and it works without problem...

Comment: `$link = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'login');
$query = "DELETE FROM test WHERE id=$id";

mysqli_query($link, $query) OR die(mysqli_error($link));`

Comment: yeah i did that i don't get an error. it just refreshes the page with the url being /faqDelete.php?id=11, but it didn't delete anything. should i give a JSFiddle with both my codes? even though it won't actually code anything, you could see if i'm on the right track?

Comment: i found out my error. i didn't include the database :/ nevermind thanks for helping out I figured it out thanks to you!

Comment: Have fun :)  Also, you can use header('Location: http://youradminpage'); to get back... 

If you want it all to happen without refreshing the page, you should read up on AJAX.

Comment: Escape your data instead putting directly into your query! And separate the php variable from your string. So it should be: $query = "DELETE FROM test WHERE id=" . (int)$id . ";";

Answer (score 2):

If you have in the database:

```
Id | Question
--------------------------
1  | This is a question
2  | This is question 2
```

And when you render your page and have a own delete page

```
<?php
//You have get the questions by a query and stored in the local $sqlResults
echo "<table>
        <tr><th>Id</th><th>Question</th><th>Delete</th></tr>";
foreach($sqlResults as $result)
{
  echo "<tr><td>" . $result["id"] . "</td><td>" . $result["question"] . "</td>";
  echo "<td><a href='your-domain.com/delete.php?id=" . $result["id"] . "'>X</a></td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

And when you have a javascript function which makes a AJAX post call, make the href like:

```
yourDeleteJavascriptFunction(" . $result["id"] . ")
```

In both cases you render a list, and per item you add the id of the question. You can get the value when you receive the id and delete only that question by his id ;-)

Comment: this is sort of what I'm looking for, but I don't really understand the last part. is that in a separate file? how would I do that?

Comment: @user3700201 how you mean? When you using AJAX (Javascript) you can set an action to the href. Like: <a href="javascript:actionToCalled();">An javascript action</a>. In that case you can update a small part of the webpage instead refreshing the full page.

Comment: ahh... well i figured out how to delete stuff. I just implemented a delete code as the person above did and autogenerated it, connected it with the id, now I can remove the ID of it

Comment: @user3700201 keep in mind to secure your data! If I change the ID i will be able to delete an other entity! Further escape your data! Never put a local directly to your queries without escaping them. Escaping avoids sql injection!

Answer (score 0):

best way you can use ajax call and call php file and pass id to that file and write delete query in that php file